# Alternative to OpenEphyra

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I'm working on packaging Sirius for openSUSE and I'm a bit blocked, not because of the many, many external dependencies but thanks to OpenEphyra. Actually, OpenEphyra is barely broken and pretty unmaintained. I would like to purpose a viable alternative to replace it. Does anyone know an interesting and a functional alternative ?

Thanks for any further help.

Regards.
Benjamin

Comment: The post has *speech-recognition* tag, so what exactly do you want to get from OpenEphyra? Is it only ASR?

Comment: OpenEphyra as a questions-answers framework. I've seen another post about alternatives but those purposed are unsatisfying in my opinion.